# Call functions from string & replace result in existing string

Tags: javascript, replace

I have below string which contains some functions names, so I need to call those function & whaterver values/result came from function need to replace in existing string (instead of function name)

My String

```
my_computer/project_folder/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()
```

Need output like:

```
my_computer/project_folder/customer=Customer1/userData.csv/controller=myController
```

I am getting function names from string using below:

```
let functions = parquetUploadPath.split("/")
            .filter(element => element.endsWith("()"))
            .map(element => element.split("=")[1] ?? element.split("=")[0]);
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and what you're specifically stuck with in your attempt.

Comment: I have separate out function names from given string using below code:

let functions = str.split("/")
                .filter(element => element.endsWith("()"))
                .map(element => element.split("=")[1] ?? element.split("=")[0]);  

Now I dont understand how to call those functions?

Comment: Are you able to [edit] that into your question please to that it's formatted/easier to read for others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use functions in this way but you can use variables in strings.

```
const customer = getCustomer(); const csvFileName = getCsvFileName();
const controllerName getControllerName();
const myString = `my_computer/project_folder/customer=${customer}/${csvFileName}/controller=${controller}`;
```

BUT if you need to extrapolate the functions from the string, you need to parse the string. In this case I suggest you to identify function by delimiters. Run the functions with eval() and then update the string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I misunderstood something, but you can use a template literal

```
 `my_computer/project_folder/customer=${getCustomer()}/${getCsvFileName()}/controller=${getControllerName()}`
```